# Android Application Deployment on Android Device

Tags: android, deployment

I have developed the Google map application in android using Eclipse and AVD. Is it possible to run the application on device or I need any development certificate to install application on device (just like iPhone).

Kindly guide me so that I can test my application on my device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need a certificate you need a phone with debugging enabled. Read this article:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

After an successful installation of your app, you might want to read this article:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html

Although you might want to ask at stackoverflow.com for programming related questions.