# How to run android apps on real devices?

Tags: android

Based on the link given below: https://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Win7 , it seems like I need to install the driver of my phone in order for me to deploy my apps to my phone. However, followed the steps stated but failed to update driver. I'm using Samsung Galaxy Note GTN7000 that having Android version 4.1.2. I tried to search for driver online but it seems my laptop already have the updated driver, but yet, I failed to deplopy apps to my phone. May I know what went wrong?

Comment: Have you set USB debugging to true in device settings? Settings > Developer Options > USB Debugging. Please make sure this checkbox is checked.

Comment: Run `adb devices` in your console to check if your device is recognized.

Comment: @Dhruti: Yes I've made sure USB Debugging was checked. As I said I've followed all the listed steps

Comment: @bigdestroyer: There wasn't any devices attached

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Application Deployment on Android Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121438/android-application-deployment-on-android-device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install Kies on your system.
2. Enable Debugging mode on your phone by Settings > Developer Options > USB Debugging.
3. Now run your project. If still your device is not being shown on device list, then 
   (i). Go to the path of Elipse > SDK > Platform-Tools on command line
   (ii). Run following commands-

   > ./adb kill-server
   >
   > ./adb devices

Answer (score 0):

Download your manufacturer driver , in your case it is [kies](http://www.samsung.com/nl/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/). It Android studio or eclipse will recognise it when phone is contented by USB.

Let the android now your are a developer by opening developer option. If you're on android 4.0+ pressed 7 times on build info to add this option too the settings.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Samsung Android USB driver in [here](http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Android-USB-Driver-for-Windows;jsessionid=nm1MJGGBFPHL5qWMsfG91xbXKGDljLCj2WKQGFYMp7Nc16NC0vY8!-1559510965) then install it in your PC
2. make sure that you have turned on `USB Debugging` in your phone setting in :

   Settings -> Developer Options -> USB Debugging
3. If `developer Options` is not display in your setting, click several times on build info to display this option to the settings.